# Android ListView custom ArrayAdapter - setting style of item TextView not working consistently

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

Having a weird issue here where the ListView doesn't render what the code reflects when debugging or in LogCat output.

It's pretty simple. I'm populating a ListView using a custom ArrayAdapter, with some POJO entities. The data is correct and works perfectly, no issues there. When a user clicks one of the items I'm setting a flag in the table to mark the record as 'read'. In the ArrayAdapter, I'm checking for that flag and setting the item bold if it's unread.

Problem: The first item is never un-bolded until all other items are clicked, first. I can click item 1, go back, and it's still bold. I can then click item 2, go back, and then both items 1 and 2 are no longer bold. It's the same no matter how many items I click. Also, some other testers here have seen other inconsistencies where all items will become bold, then upon returning to the Activity from another, they're no longer bold.

I've logged and debugged, the entities passing through all reflect correct data, exactly as expected. It's the rendering that doesn't correctly reflect the data.

It's my first one, I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.

My ArrayAdapter:

```
public class MessageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Message>
{
    private List<Message> messages;

    public MessageAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Message> entities)
    {
        super(context, resource, entities);
        this.messages = entities;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if (convertView == null) 
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_message, parent, false);

        Message message = this.messages.get(position);

        if (message != null)
        {
            TextView messageText = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.messageItemText);
            messageText.setText(String.format("Type: %s Received: %s", message.getType(), StringUtil.getDateTime(message.getReceived())));

            if (message.getIsRead() == 0)
                messageText.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        }       

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

My Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  List<Message> msgData = data.getAll();
  MessageAdapter adapter = new MessageAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item_message, msgData);
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: add else condition to your if: 

if (message.getIsRead() == 0)
                messageText.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
else 
                messageText.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to add else statement to your if condition

```
if (message.getIsRead() == 0)
                messageText.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
else 
                messageText.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
```